# How to add values to this iOS Bar Chart in White and 14px using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I have a bar chart which currently looks like this:

[image]

I would like to put the value of each bar at the end of the bar in white.

This is my current code:

```
viewDidLoad{
 self.results =  ["Lost", "Drawn", "Won"]
 let games = [total_Losses, total_Draws, total_Wins]
 self.setChart(dataPoints: self.results, values: games)
}


func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]){

    let formato:BarChartFormatter = BarChartFormatter()
    let xaxis:XAxis = XAxis()
    let  xAxis : XAxis = self.barChartView.xAxis;
    barChartView.noDataText = "you need to provide some data for the chart."

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = Array()

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        formato.stringForValue (Double(i), axis: xaxis)
    }

    xaxis.valueFormatter = formato
    barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = xaxis.valueFormatter

    xAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 14.0)!
    xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Games Played")
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: [chartDataSet])
    chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()


    barChartView.leftAxis.enabled = true
    barChartView.legend.enabled = false
    barChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""

    chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
    barChartView.data = chartData
    barChartView.leftAxis.forceLabelsEnabled = true
    barChartView.rightAxis.forceLabelsEnabled = true

    barChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1.0

    barChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    barChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

    barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    barChartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
    self.barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxis.LabelPosition.bottom

}
```

How do I add values to the bars in this chart, in white and pixel size 14?

**The answers so far have failed to work - I think the problem may lie within:**

```
for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        formato.stringForValue (Double(i), axis: xaxis) // This line has a warning: "Result of call to 'stringForValue(_:axis:)' is unused
    }
```

This above snippet of code calls this class below:

```
public class BarChartFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter
{
var matches: [String]! = ["Lost", "Drawn", "Won"]

public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String
{
    return matches[Int(value)]
}   
}
```

Comment: I believe you can set the labels on the x-axis to be enabled (as well as set their font and color).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the color and fonts using the `BarChartData` class object. For your case, it is `chartData`

Follow below code in order to set the required fonts and color of labels.

```
chartData.setValueFont(UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0))
chartData.setValueTextColor(UIColor.white)
```

In case you want to show the label within the bar then set your `BarChartView` object property `drawValueAboveBarEnabled` to false. It will render your labels within the bars.

```
barChartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = false
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work - I think the problem could lie elsewhere?  I have updated the question above. Thanks